# Android Native Activity AssetManager VS 2019 Not Working

Tags: c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2019, android-assetmanager

I am trying to load an image and a text file using the `AAssetManager` in the Android Native Activity in VS 2019.  I've tried every combination of paths I could think of to get `AAssetManager_openDir` or `AAssetManager_open` to give me a file.  Solutions I've found elsewhere were related to incorrect paths or the `AAssetManager` object wasn't valid.

Here is how I'm trying to get access to my image and text files.

```
    AAssetManager* pMan = m_pApp->activity->assetManager;
    AAsset*     pAsset = AAssetManager_open(pMan, "drawable\\testpng", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER); // Always returns NULL
    AAssetDir*  pAssetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(pMan, "res\\drawable");
    const char* szFilename;
    while ((szFilename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(pAssetDir)) != NULL)
    {
        // 'szFilename' is always NULL and this print never gets hit
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Debug", szFilename);
    }
```

This is my `Android.Packaging` project.

[image: Android Package Project]

Android Manifest

```
<string name="testpng">drawable\test.png</string>
<string name="testdrawtxt">drawable\testtext.txt</string>
<string name="testpng2">drawable\assets\test2.png</string>
<string name="testdrawtxt2">drawable\assets\testtext2.txt</string>
```

And finally the actual output directory
[image: Resources output directory]

The asset manager is valid as far as I know.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assets should not be under **res**, but on the same level of hieararchy.

Comment: That was it!  I spent too long on this and I was just putting it in the wrong directory.  I created a folder called "assets" next to the "res" folder and put the items inside there.  Simply calling `AAssetManager_open(pMan, "test.png", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER)`  worked with no problems.

Thanks very much.  Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets should not be under **res**, but on the same level of hieararchy.